# HTTP request from Adobe InDesign script?

Tags: rest, httpwebrequest, adobe, adobe-indesign

I add a button in Adobe InDesign with an action to perform request xml from restful webservice, but I couldn't find any objects like XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject. I don't know there is any object in sdk that lets me do that job?

Comment: I found a solution to do this http://www.rorohiko.com/podcast/geturl.zip

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but since it has not been marked as answered yet I'll add one more option for future searchers.

Check out the [Extendables](http://extendables.org/) library for InDesign - it has that plus many other things you should be using.